# React: Cant find blocking component using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I think its due to how I am updating the location but I am not sure.

The way I do it is like so:

```
<Route render={props => <Somecomponent location={props.location} /> } />
```

Then in Somecomponent I do the following:

```
someAction(context){
   globals.context = context
   // some other stuff that triggers an event ELSEWHERE
   // that event will update the location via this context variable
}

...
render(){
 return <Route render={context => {
       return <div onClick={() => this.someActionThatChangesLocation(context)}
```

}}/>
    }

ELSEWHERE:

```
someEvent(){
   globals.context.history.push("/newlocation")
}
```

What happens is, the URL gets updated but not the view. So I am stuck with the old view.

How can I find out which component is the one thats blocking the render?

I added the location prop because I read that that would make trigger a rerender but its not working so I assume the blocking component is a different one.

I am not sure how to further debug this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Im not sure what exactly fixed the issue now because I changed a lot until it finally worked.

1. My App component is now wrapped like so:

   `class AppWrapper extends Component {
         render() {
           return <Router>
              <Route component={withRouter(App)} />
           </Router>
         }
      }`
2. I dont use `globals.context` anymore because now I can access `this.props.history` inside App.js component
3. I made sure that that is the only Router in my app. Before I had the Router component inside my App as well as in the Wrapper and I think that blocked the update for some reason, not sure though.